# How to parse the below xml string in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

I have the below xml string in one string variable.

```
string xmlString = "<a:ORegions>
                             <a:ID>1</a:ID> 
                             <a:regionCode>US</a:regionCode> 
                    </a:ORegions>
                    <a:ORegions>
                             <a:ID>2</a:ID> 
                             <a:regionCode>CANADA</a:regionCode> 
                    </a:ORegions>
                    <a:ORegions>
                    <a:ID>3</a:ID> 
                             <a:regionCode>ASIA</a:regionCode> 
                    </a:ORegions>
```

Now i want to access regionCode values, that is US, CANADA, ASIA

How i can do that using c#. I am new to xml parsing.

Comment: *"Please suggest me asap."* That tends to have the opposite of the effect you desire. It shouldn't, but it tends to.

Comment: "Please suggest me asap" sounds like you should hire someone and not get us to do your dirty work.

Comment: ...or do some googling on C# and XML. Your example is fairly simple to parse...

Comment: If you have not yet tried anything, I'd recommend starting with `XDocument.Load` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(filePath);

foreach (XmlNode node in document.GetElementsByTagName("a:regionCode"))
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can deserialize that string (assuming you fix the various syntax errors) via the `System.Xml` namespace classes, particularly [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx), such as with its [`Load` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807.aspx). To access the namespaces (`a` in `a:Oregions` and such is a namespace), you'll want an [`XmlNamespaceManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.aspx). You'd then register the namespaces (they must be defined somewhere) with the manager and use that when querying the `XmlDocument`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LinqToXml`

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
```

You can then access elements, values and attributes within:

```
XNamespace xmlNamespace = "a";

//e.g. Retrieve's a list of regioncodes...
var ids = doc.Elements(xmlNamespace + "ORegions")
             .Select(r => r.Element("regionCode").Value);
```